# Using AVAudioPlayer with Dynamic URL in Swift 3 causing Thread Errors

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am new to Swift and making an audio app using `AVAudioPlayer`. I am using a remote URL mp3 file for the audio, and this works when it's static.

For my use case, I want to pull a URL for an mp3 file from a JSON array and then pass it into the `AVAudioPlayer` to run.

1. If I move the `AVAudioPlayer` block into the `ViewDidLoad` and make the mp3 file a static URL, it will run fine.
2. Then, when I move this code into my block that extracts an mp3 url from JSON, I can `print` the URL successfully. But when I pass it into my audio player, problems arise. Here's the code.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

       let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com/example.json")
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
               guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

               let json: Any?
               do{
                   json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
               }
               catch{
                   return
               }

               guard let data_list = json as? [[String:Any]] else {
                   return
               }
               if let foo = data_list.first(where: {$0["episode"] as? String == "Example Preview"}) {

                   self.audiotest = (foo["audio"] as? String)!
                   print(self.audiotest) // this prints 

                   // where i'm passing it into the audio player
                   if let audioUrl = URL(string: self.audiotest) {

                       // then lets create your document folder url
                       let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

                       // lets create your destination file url
                       let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)

                       //let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: destinationUrl, withExtension: "mp3")!

                       do {
                           audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl)

                       } catch let error {
                           print(error.localizedDescription)
                       }
                   } // end player

   // ....
   ```

Specifically, I get an error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` when clicking a play button `IBAction` that is connected to the audio player. Finally, that action function looks like this:

```
  @IBAction func playPod(_ sender: Any) {
    audioPlayer.play() 
}
```

Do you know where I'm going wrong? I'm confused as to why I can't print the URL and also get a response that the URL is nil in the same block, but maybe that's an asynchronous thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't save the mp3 file to documents and trying to play it

this line

```
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl)
```

assumes that there is a saved mp3 file in that path , but acutally there is no files you appended the audio extension on the fly

besides for steaming audio from a remote server, use **AVPlayer** instead of AVAudioPLayer.
[AVPlayer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Also try this with urls parsed from json

```
  var urlStr = (foo["audio"] as? String)!

  self.audiotest = urlStr.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
```

Comment: Interesting. I do save it in a previous view but maybe I am having an issue accessing. Do you have a sense of why it would play outside the block (when I make the URL the same but hard code it in as a value rather than responding to the var)? That's what I don't get.

Comment: is there any space in the https path

Comment: Hey, I verified your answer. I added a download button in the previous view controller. What's cool is that by targeting that URL in the second VC (as shown above), it now knows to find it in the bundle which I thought was going to be hard. Much appreciated!