# Extract [URL] to a URL

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to extract the audio file referenced by the Firebase database url. The function I created goes as far as downloading the `[URL]` but AVAudioPlayer needs a `URL` that it can play from locally. The overall goal is to stream the audio file. My question is is there any way to export this url from the array to a regular url string? This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48431455/using-avaudioplayer-with-dynamic-url-in-swift-3-causing-thread-errors) is the closest I can that relates to my question but doesn't really help. Below is the code snippet and screenshot of the JSON path. Any help and guidance is much appreciated!

```
func fetchAudio(asset: AVURLAsset){
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference() //Referencing database
    var node : Post? //References the Post model
    let remoteAudioURL = FetchAudio.shared.storageRef.reference(forURL: (node?.audioUrl)!) //Referencing the remote audio file by way of it's respective Post
    let localURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) //Instantiate the local destination for the downloaded audio file

    remoteAudioURL.getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print (error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            if let d = data {
                do {
                    try d.write(to: localURL) //Error: Cannot convert value of type '[URL]' to expected argument type 'URL'
                    self.player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: localURL) //Error: Cannot convert value of type '[URL]' to expected argument type 'URL'
                    self.player?.play()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @mojtabaalmoussawi the name of the audio file is autogenerated string. Ex: VqQosRzUMT.m4a. It's done this way when posted to the Firebase Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)`

you are getting all of the urls which is not what you need to **play a specific audio file or saving it**.

So to acheive that you may need to ask the FileManager to generate the url where your file will be, by doing this :

```
      let localURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                appropriateFor: nil,
                                                create: false)
                        .appendingPathComponent("yourFileName.mp3")
```

Comment: Thank you, mojtaba. This seems to have fixed my issue. Appreciate the help!